# Qt add a round rect to a Graphics Item Group

Tags: qt, graphics

I would like to know how to create a rounded rectangle with qt and add it to a QGraphicsItemGroup (Qt is 4.8).

I have the code like:

```
QGraphicsItemGroup* grp = new QGraphicsItemGroup();    
QRect rct(x, y, width, height);
QGraphicsRectItem* frame = new QGraphicsRectItem(rct, grp);
```

but this (obviously) created and added a rectangle to the group... and I would like to have a rounded rectangle. Unfortunately I did not find anything similar to what I need... a simple `QGraphicsRoundRectItem` class.

Anyone has any experience with this?

Comment: There's no built-in type for that, you'll need to create your own - and there's quite a few complete examples on the web already.

Answer (score 3):

Create a class that inherits from QGraphicsItem

Then, override the object's paint item and call the painter function drawRoundedRect.

You can then instantiate the new object and add it to the QGraphicsItemGroup.

Comment: And don't forget to reimplement the boundingRect() pure virtual method.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `QPainterPath`, add a round rectangle as path, add the path to the scene to obtain a `QGraphicsPathItem` and fill it with a brush or draw the outline with a pen. This item can then be added to any `QGraphicsItemGroup`.

Example (Python/Qt binding)

```
path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
path.addRoundRect(QtCore.QRectF(x, y, w, h), rw, rh)
item = self.scene.addPath(path, pen=my_pen, brush=my_brush)
# add item to item group
```

See the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainterpath.html) of `QPainterPath` for more ways to add round rectangles.